# questions about dir and import in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

I have some questions about Python's dir function

```
>>>import urllib
>>>dir(urllib)
['__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__','__loader__','__name__','__package__', '__path__', '__spec__']
```

And when I do like this

```
>>>import urllib.request
>>>dir(urllib)
['__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__','__package__', '__path__', '__spec__', 'error', 'parse', 'request', 'response']
```

Why it comes three more attributes?
Why the request attribute doesn't in the dir(urllib) at first?

I' really appriciate your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`urllib` is a package, whereas  in `urllib.request`, `request` is a module inside the `urllib` package.

When you import a package, it does not automatically import modules inside the package, unless that module is imported by the `__init__.py` for that package.

But the `__init__.py` of `urllib` is empty (its empty in my *Python 3.4*) , and hence when simply importing `urllib` it does not import the module `urllib.request`.

Comment: By the way, `__init__.py` of `urllib` package is also empty in my *Python 3.5*.

Comment: Thank you.And I wonder what happened to urllib when I import the urllib.request so that make the dir() return different values?

Comment: request module was added as an attribute of the `urllib` module object when you imported it. And other modules that got imported when you imported `urllib.request` .

Comment: (my naive opinion)> The importing of request of urllib shouldn't create or modify  at a external scope (that means, urllib will only become a new accessible name and nothing more). It seems like a child process modifying the parent node - and this is weird to me at first glance. I really don't get the point. Could some help me to understand this feature of python modules?